# Unable to retrieve contents of element id

Tags: excel, vba, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname, mshtml

Unable to retrieve elements contents using excel vba

```
Option Explicit
Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLButtons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLbutton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLTables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

Sub Test1()

Dim URL As String, PriceNSE As Object
URL = "https://www.google.com/finance/quote/TATAMOTORS:NSE"

With XMLPage
    .Open "GET", URL, False
    .send
End With

Set PriceNSE = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("YMlKec fxKbKc")(0)
Debug.Print PriceNSE.innerText

End Sub
```

I have tried to getelemenybyid, but no yielded no result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the HTTP response text to your HTML document as follows...

```
With XMLPage
    .Open "GET", URL, False
    .send
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With
```

**EDIT**

For your follow-up question, try...

```
Dim txt As String
Dim pos As Long
txt = SymbolNSE.innerText
txt = Mid$(txt, 1 + IIf(Left$(txt, 4) = "Home", 4, 0))
pos = InStr(1, txt, " ")
If pos > 0 Then
    txt = Left$(txt, pos - 1)
End If

Debug.Print txt
```

Comment: In the same code if i introduce  Set SymbolNSE = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("PdOqHc")(0)   yields me output HomeTATAMOTORS • NSE , how do i get only "TATAMOTORS" as output ignoring other texts attached along "TATAMOTORS" @Domenic